# Power Shell CSOM browser authentication

Tags: powershell, csom, authentication, web

I want to connect to sharepiont site with browser authentication becouse mobile verifcation is on sharepiont. can any help me with this.

thanks 
Waqas

Answer (score 1):

Use following method to authenticate browser.

- ClientContext = Which holds the entire tenant/domain informations
- Web = Holds the requested site details from the tenant
- SecureString = Holds encrypt the plain password for the server authendication
- SharePointOnlineCredentials = Its a authendication service

`public ClientContext Auth(String uname, String pwd,string siteURL) {
    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteURL);
    Web web = context.Web;
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
    try
    {
        context.Load(web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Olla! from " + web.Title + " site");
        return context;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong in Auth Module" + e);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return null; 
    }
}`